# layout is not setting. How to place divs on top of main div

Tags: html, css

I want to set layout something like 
[image: Desire Layout]

What i thought that i will have to set some thing like this

[image: Scath]

Means main div, and on the top of main div, i have other divs. I used something like this

```
<div id="headerImage" >

        <div id="help_About">               
            <a href="#">Help</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>                                           
        </div>

        <div id="myLogout">               
            <input type="text" value="Basit" />
            <a href="#">Logout</a>                                                          
        </div>

        <div id="myImage">
            <img width="20" height="20" src="resources/images/tools_icon.png" /> 
        </div>

        <img src="resources/images/2b.jpg"/>

    </div>

    #headerImage{ 
        border-style :solid;
        border-width: thin;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20%;           
        background: url(${imgUrl}/2b.jpg) no-repeat top left;            
        padding: 0px;
        border-top: 0px;
        border-bottom: 5px #eeeeee solid;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    #headerImage #help_About{ 
        margin-left: 10%
        margin-top: 2%;
        display: inline-block;
        border-style :solid;
        border-width: thin;                                 
        padding: 2px;
        border-top: 2px;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    #headerImage #myLogout{ 
        margin-left: 30%
        margin-top: 4%;
        display: inline-block;
        border-style :solid;
        border-width: thin;                                 
        padding: 2px;
        border-top: 2px;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    #headerImage #myImage{ 
        margin-right: 10%
        margin-top: 4%;
        display: inline-block;
        border-style :solid;
        border-width: thin;                                 
        padding: 2px;
        border-top: 2px;
        z-index: 2;
    }
```

I just gave the border style and width and height for physical appearance. But then i am getting something like this

[image]

what i am doing wrong? How can i set the layout of my divs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/SQwFK/

HTML

```
<header>
    <div id="left"></div>

    <div id="rightTop"></div>
    <div id="rightBottom"></div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
    header {
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/300);
    height: 300px;
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
}

#left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    background: #ffe;
    height: 100px;
    width: 250px;
}

#rightTop, #rightBottom {
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    top: 25px;
    background: #fef;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

#rightBottom {
    top: 175px;
}
```

**New EDIT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Working

```
<div id="headerImage" >
....
</div>
<div id="menuBodyContainer" >
    <div id="menu">
    </div>
    <div id="myBody">
    </div>  
</div>
```

Now i tried with your code like

```
  #headerImage{ 
        position: absolute;
        border-style :solid;
        border-width: thin;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20%;           
        background: url(${imgUrl}/2b.jpg) no-repeat top left;            
        padding: 0px;
        border-top: 0px;
        border-bottom: 5px #eeeeee solid;
        z-index: 1;            
    }

    #headerImage #help_About{ 
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        top: 4%;
        left: 4%;
        opacity:0.4;
        z-index: 2;            
    }

    #headerImage #myLogout{ 
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        right: 50px;
        top: 25px;
        z-index: 2;           
    }

    #headerImage #myImage{
        position: absolute;
        top: 2%;
        right: 2%;
        z-index: 2;           
    }
```

This is working.

[image]

But i have another problem now. As you can see i set the `#help_About and #myLogout {display:inline-block}`. But `#help_About` making a big square. Also i want that the white square don't show. It appears that the elements in the div are actually on the image. Same for #myLogout. I set display to inlne-block but they are appearing on two different lines, i want then inline and also it is showing white square as a background i don't want it. How can i do it? If i set transparency then it set the transparency of whole div including elements not just div. tThanks

Now what ?

Comment: I have removed the line `<img src="resources/images/2b.jpg"/>` from my headerImage div. set position to relative and all inside div set to absolute as you did but why i am getting screen like the above :(

Comment: I think it's because of `height: 20%` Try to give it a `px` based value height and see if it helps

Comment: I removed the heights, widths and backgrounds from those div-s. Updated your edit CSS - use that

Comment: Thanks but div still taking a whole square if i check it with firebug. Isn't there a way that the div take the width and height of the including contents only? Also i have two links like `<div id="help_About"> <a href="#">Help</a><a href="#">About</a>                                           </div>` and `<div id="myLogout">               
 <h:outputLabel value="Basit" />
                <a href="#">Logout</a>                                                          
            </div>` How can i put a space between the two elements? Thanks

Comment: What div takes the whole square? I've checked here - http://jsfiddle.net/ku6bW/ Everything seems to be fine. Also I've added a rule for the first `<a>` and applied a `margin-right` to it, so you can change it to increase/decrease the space between the links

Comment: HHmmm thank you very much :). Is it necessary to set display to inline block for a, as you wrote `#help_About a:first-child {display: inline-block;..}`? Because the div in which a is present has display inline-block, and elements inherit properties of their parent?

Comment: you can try to remove it :) I just put it there in case it's defaulted to inline by some CSS reset or smth.

Answer (score 0):

You need to absolutely position your divs.  Then you use top, left, right or bottom properties to align the divs where you want them.

The image you have set as the background is also being used in an image tag and that is likely the cause of the doubling up of your header image.

**Update**

Set the parent div(in your case `#headerImage`) to `position:relative;` and all child divs should be given `position:absolute;`

Comment: you mean set absolute position on all divs or only on main div ?

Comment: @Basit just the ones you want to overlap should be enough - so all the divs excluding the main div (the one on the bottom that you're not moving)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create header div with backgroung of your wave image. And then place all inner controls:

html

```
<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a><li>        
        <li><a href="#">Help</a><li>
    </ul>
    <a class="logo" href="#"></a>
    <a class="logout">Logout</a>
</div>​
```

css

```
body { font-family: Verdana; }
#header { height:100px; background: url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18372729/header-bg.png')}
#header ul { top:23px; left:270px; position:absolute; }
#header ul li { display:inline; }
#header ul li a { color:#fff; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:none; margin:20px; font-size:10pt; font-weight:bold; }
#header ul li a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
#header .logo { position:absolute; top:20px; right:200px; background:url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18372729/logo.png'); width:217px; height:75px; display:block; position:absolute; }
#header .logout { font-size:9pt; float:right; margin-top:80px; margin-right:20px; }​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xsDQP/1/